# Motherboard with embeded CPU for HTPC

Tags: motherboard, uhd, htpc

This question is here after I ask this one: [UHD compatible Graphic Card](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4275/uhd-compatible-graphic-card)

The thing is that I have a HTPC and would like to be able to read UHD movies (since the i3's IGP cannot). As you can see in the previous question, finding a passive GPU with UHD display is impossible for now.

However, during my researches, I found a motherboard that embed a CPU (Pentium J3710) http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/J3710-ITX/index.us.asp. Following the description, it should be able to do UHD.

This motherboard is a good start but appart from the Asrock's description, if I go onto the Intel website, I cannot find any information about this CPU and its IGP (espectially the maximum resolution). However, it doesn't support RAID (which is mandatory for me). I didn't find another product like this. Maybe you could ?

Here are my requirements for a motherboard that embed a CPU:

- Preferably passive and low counsumption
- UHD resolution output with hardware h265 decoding
- At least 3 SATA connectors (2 for RAID, one for BlueRay). 3 or 6GB/s, I don't mind
- My current chassis is Micro-ATX so no ATX, but Micro-ATX or Mini-ITX are ok

**EDIT**
Obviously, 4k60 is preferred, but any suggestion, even 4k30 is welcome.

Comment: 4k30 or 4k60?  I know for a fact cherry trail does 4k60 in many cases.

Comment: however, about cherry trail familly, it's mobile SoC isn't it? In any cases, I didn't find any reseller that sell it. I saw some Sticks embedding a cherry trail SoC, but since it's only a stick, it cannot do any RAID configuration

Comment: Yup and it's got a pretty cut down igp that does 4k30 with dual channel ram

Comment: So, even if it does 4k30, I'm affraid I cannot use it for RAID

Comment: Intel ARK is a great source for info regarding Intel CPUs. [Pentium J3710 Link](http://ark.intel.com/products/91532/Intel-Pentium-Processor-J3710-2M-Cache-up-to-2_64-GHz)

Comment: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/quick-reference-guide-to-intel-processor-graphics seems to list which families of IGP might do 4k. Even if it does 4k60, you *need* dp or HDMI 2.0 to output it.  I'd also add passive CPUs rely on case fans for cooling and a lower end, fan cooled CPU/stock heat sink is pretty quiet

Comment: @comicurus is the idea of using miracast a bad one for some reason?

Comment: @AdamWykes well it didn't know this technology but, for some reason (I don't know why) for sound and video I am really attached to wires. For me it sounds strange to be able to send high rates signal wireless while we can't through wires... As I said in comment to your answer, thank you for your try, but I'll be waiting for the market to develop a bit around the UHD for HTPC. Maybe in one year or less? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically, the [ASRock QC5000-ITX/PH](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813157595&nm_mc=AFC-C8Junction&cm_mmc=AFC-C8Junction-PCPartPicker,%20LLC-_-na-_-na-_-na&cm_sp=&AID=10446076&PID=3938566&SID=) will get you to

> 4K x 2K (4096x2160) @ 30Hz

But I don't know. I've built seven or eight rigs with that board inside of it and I would say my confidence level is *low*. The Pentium J3710 - even less so. It doesn't support DP 1.2, so it can't do "real" 4K. AsRock claims

> 4K x 2K (3840x2160) @ 30Hz

For that board.

All of this is really low-power stuff, as you might expect from an embedded system. A non-embedded equivalent with slightly more oomph, which might just be enough to drive a 4k30 display, would be something like an Athlon 5370 on the [ASRock AM1H-ITX](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813157491&nm_mc=AFC-C8Junction&cm_mmc=AFC-C8Junction-PCPartPicker,%20LLC-_-na-_-na-_-na&cm_sp=&AID=10446076&PID=3938566&SID=) motherboard. But that STILL doesn't get you hardware RAID.

HDMI 2.0 appears to be available on Skylake motherboards, or at least some kind of HDMI technology which offers full 4K, but unfortunately it doesn't get you 30hz; only 24hz.

**There's no one motherboard with an embedded chip on the market that gets you all of what you want.**

**BUT**, there is a very similar solution:

```
PCPartPicker part list: http://pcpartpicker.com/list/GGs7TH
Price breakdown by merchant: http://pcpartpicker.com/list/GGs7TH/by_merchant/

CPU: AMD A8-7600 3.1GHz Quad-Core Processor  ($71.99 @ SuperBiiz) 
Motherboard: MSI A68HI AC Mini ITX FM2+ Motherboard  ($81.98 @ Newegg) 
Memory: Klevv Urbane 8GB (2 x 4GB) DDR3-2400 Memory  ($35.99 @ Newegg) 
Other: Belkin Miracast Video Adapter (Supports HDMI 2.0) ($59.99)
Total: $249.95
Prices include shipping, taxes, and discounts when available
Generated by PCPartPicker 2016-08-02 14:55 EDT-0400
```

This fits in your current case and runs on your current PSU, with your current storage solutions. It supports RAID 0/1/10 off the FCH's SATA controller for all four possible SATA connections, and, while it cannot do a hardwired 4K connection, it supports a CPU and wireless solution with the oomph and the technology necessary to drive a *4k60* connection to your TV in true, full 4k resolution, with the help of the [Belkin Miracast Video Adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HFAEBWG). The wireless card connects in the 5ghz frequency range with the adapter, which is plugged directly into the HDMI 2.0 port on your TV, and then you enable miracast using a charm in Windows 8.1 or 10 (or on any Android device with an OS of 4.2 or higher). Apparently this also works in linux via the [MiracleCast](https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast) software, but I'm not confident in that. It is true that this would require a second connection (either using the built-in ethernet or another wifi adapter in a USB or PCI-E port) to actually get online content onto your screen, but I'm guessing due to the RAID requirement that this is not a big deal.

Of course, this is NOT embedded and NOT passively cooled, so if that's a dealbreaker then I guess we are SOL. I'm hoping that it isn't since your current build seems not to be.

This was the only solution I could find which comes close to what you're looking for. It is true that you could use this dongle with an Intel system that supported Miracast, and there may be other similar HDMI 2.0 miracast adapters out there, but this was the configuration which seemed best-supported and most cost-effective from my point of view. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer, I've been busy these last days. Even if your answer is not exactly what I was looking for, this is the most convincing attempt that try to meets my requirements. Also, I knew that it is tricky to answer perfectly to what I asked. Finally, I think I will be waiting to find what I initially asked for :)

Comment: For your remark about 4K claimed by Asrock, the "true" 4K resolution (cinema) is 4096x2160 while the UHD resolution (for TVs) is 3840x2160.

Comment: @comicurus, thanks for being so beneficent. I always get stuck on resolution numbers so sorry for that mixup. It does look like Intel compute sticks due out later this year are going to have 4k30 over HDMI, so RAID is the only remaining problem - but since they have 32gb eMMC on board, perhaps you could allocate some of that as a cache to an external HDD using software like primocache - should offer faster performance than RAID...

Comment: I didn't precise but I use RAID 1 so performance isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: And the solution HAS to be an embedded design?

Comment: Absolutely not. The idea behind me question was that "If cannot find a GPU that does what I want (first question quoted), I may find a motherboard with a embeded CPU/IGP that does". But if by "embeded" design you mean something like the Intel's sticks, then not, I want to keep my chassis / APU / raid1 config / BlueRay etc.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest 4k unit was an Acer Laptop quad A4 amd and Intel HD 4800 plugged into external sceptre and went straight to 4k even without the 48 Gbps hdmi cable, very inexpensive it was older unit and power went on it if now would go A10 and the 4800 Intel HD for quality, though using a Sony e series currently, good A4 and HD setup is good inexpensive 4k grapics though, at least quad core and you have to use system config to activate all the cores.

Comment: Welcome on the HwRecs SE! We typically use sentences.